# use solvePnP to calculate the pose with four non-planar points

Tags: opencv

I want to use solvePnP to calculate the pose of the object.
My question is 
1. The model points have to be co-planar?
2. Is it OK the model points are defined in left hand coordinate?

Thanks.

EJ.

Comment: If the model points (four points) are not co-planar, how to calculate the pose?

Comment: You could look into [findFundamentalMat](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#findfundamentalmat), but it takes 8 matched pairs of points instead of 4.